# codeigniter iterate to all checkbox when appended

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, checkbox

good day to all, i have this script where i am appending checkbox when the add button is click. now my problem is that when i add two checkbox, when i click the second checkbox it triggers the first checkbox not the second checkbox.

here's my code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var TempCounter = parseInt($('input[name^="TempID"]').val());
    var count = TempCounter;
    var ajaxCount = count + 1;
    var reqCount = TempCounter;

$('#addButton').click(function(e) {
    $("#ApprovalRequestor").append('<div><input style="margin-left:20px;" type="checkbox"  id="requestorManagerChecked'+count+'" name="requestorManager['+count+']" > </input>'

    + '<span>'+document.getElementById(document.getElementById('selectOtherRequestor').value).innerHTML+'</span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete" style="margin-left:35px;">Delete</a> <input type="hidden" value="'+$('#selectOtherRequestor').val()+'" id="ApproversID" name="ApproversID['+count+']"> </input>'

    + '<input type="hidden" id="TempCount" name="TempCount" value="'+count+'"/>'

    + '<input type="hidden" id="levelID" name="levelID['+count+']" value="1"> </input> </div>');


    $('#requestorManagerChecked'+count+' ').change(function() {

        if($('#requestorManagerChecked'+reqCount+' ').is(":checked") ) {
            $('#requestorManagerChecked'+reqCount+' ').val(1);

            alert('requestorManagerChecked'+reqCount+' ');
            alert($('#requestorManagerChecked'+reqCount+' ').val() );
        }

        else {
            $('#requestorManagerChecked'+reqCount+' ').val(0);
            alert($('#requestorManagerChecked'+reqCount+' ').val() );
        }

    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'mis.php/fileApproversListController/getCounter',
        data: 'variable='+ajaxCount,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#Count').html(data);
        }
    });

    reqCount = count;
    ajaxCount++;
    count++;
});
```

here's my controller

```
function SaveApprovers() {
    $this->load->model('new_development_model');
    $requestType = $this->input->post('requestTypeID'); 
    $ApproversLists = $this->input->get_post('Approvers');

    for($ctr = 0; $ctr <= $this->input->get_post('counter'); $ctr++) {
        $ApproversLists[$ctr]['ApproversLevel'];
        $ApproversLists[$ctr]['Required'];
        $ApproversLists[$ctr]['ApproversID'];
        $Remark = $this->input->get_post('Remarks');
        $this->new_development_model->ApproversList($ApproversLists[$ctr]['ApproversLevel'], $ApproversLists[$ctr]['Required'],$ApproversLists[$ctr]['ApproversID'],$Remark);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$('#requestorManagerChecked'+count+' ').change(function()` why you added additional`' '` space there? Also make sure your id is generating unique

Comment: @ShaifulIslam yes the id it generate is unique, also the additional ' ' space is not affecting anything.

Comment: will you please provide the link to your code. I cannot understand what exactly happens

Comment: @siddhesh this is the code sir.

Comment: I mean to say i want link to see what exactly happens if you put this code online give me the link to that page so i can see the output